# ¿ Por qué da error en vpv.iso.com.viewpagervertical.VerticalViewPager?

Tags: android-studio, slide, depuración

Estoy siguiendo este tutorial: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=VQwZQz9qsDA pero cuando tengo que hacer el activity_main lo hago tal cual:

```
<vpv.iso.com.viewpagervertical.VerticalViewPager
    android:id="@id/pager"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" />
```

pero me da el siguiente error

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

causado por eso, no sé cómo hacer ya para que me funcione el slide vertical, únicamente me falla ahí. Creo que también tiene que ver que él al empezar el video tiene 2 carpetas creadas con ese nombre y yo no las tengo,  y que he creado un xml llamado pager.xml que unicamente tiene lo siguiente:

```
<resources>
<item
    type="id"
    name="pager" />
</resources>
```

Comment: cual es tu clase VerticalViewPager ? me parece que ese es el problema. ¿Cual es la dependencia que isas?

Comment: Hago lo mismo que en el video en esa parte (minuto 7:58). Si te fijas al empezar el video a la izquierda tiene carpetas con el nombre de vpv.iso.....y yo no, no sé de donde las saca..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

El problema indica que tratas de crear la vista:

```
<vpv.iso.com.viewpagervertical.VerticalViewPager
    android:id="@id/pager"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" />
```

pero **la clase `VerticalViewPager` no existe en el paquete indicado (`vpv.iso.com.viewpagervertical.`)** en tu proyecto. La vista que agregas en tu layout debe crearse vía código.

---

Te sugiero usar por ejemplo esta clase a tu proyecto:

https://android.googlesource.com/platform/packages/apps/DeskClock/+/master/src/com/android/deskclock/VerticalViewPager.java

Revisa este ejemplo:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18413309/how-to-implement-a-viewpager-with-different-fragments-layouts/46825489#46825489

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Lo he solucionado antes de mirar esto, ya que estaba poniendo el nombre del proyecto del otro y no el mio, pero me funcionaba mal, es decir, en horizontal, no entiendo, y he cogido el codigo que dices y funciona en vertical! gracias!

Comment: Un placer ayudar @RfMvs , saludos!.